# How can I link two Google accounts to one Stack Exchange account?

Tags: support, login, google-openid

I have one SO login that is linked to a Google Apps Account. The thing is... I have a second Google Apps account and I would like to add it to My Logins but nothing I have tried has worked.

I've tried editing the email address on my login profile. It now shows the second Google App email address but when I click on the Google logo to login I still have to log in to Google with the first account for the fullOfGAS username to appear when I log in to SO.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think you are doing it the right way. You should be doing the following way.

1. **Navigate to your profile page.** You can do this by clicking on your username.

   > [image: User Profile]
2. **Click on the *my logins* tab.** It should be right under the *Ask Question* button.

   > [image: My Logins Tab]
3. **Click on *add more logins...*.** Click on it.

   > [image: Add More Logins Modal]
4. **Add the desired Google Account.** Before continuing on to step five, you need to add
    the account you want to log in with via the [settings dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/).

   > [image: Add Another Google Account]
5. **Click on the big *log in with Google* button.** Seriously, click on it.

   > [image: Log In With Google]
6. **Select the account you want to sign in with.** If you want to sign in with a
    different account, click the *Sign in to another account* link.

   > [image: Sign In To Another Account]
7. **Click the *Add Login* button.** Do that and you should be good to go.

   > [image: Confirm Add Login]

And there you go, that is the *proper* way to do it.

Comment: This simply does not work for me. And I only have a single Google account. I log in using Yahoo and try to add a Google login and it seems to silently succeed but then "my logins" never shows it.

Comment: If this doesn't work, contact support using the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page, @JesseSlicer. Chances are, there's something odd about your account that we'll need to fix.

Comment: Actually, I just got an email from support yesterday which fixed the problem. It was precisely as you state. There was a duplicate account that didn't trigger an auto-merge or notification and therefore was a bit of an orphan. All good!

Comment: This no longer seems to work.  I have Google accts A and B.  My stack overflow account is linked to 'A'.  When I log in with 'A', navigate to my_logins, and click "Google" it simply takes me to my SO profile page.  There is no option to select *which* Google.

Comment: Yeah this has changed. You can no longer choose your google account. I think this change happened because of Google though. Now, if you change your Google account in Chrome it opens a new browser with its own set of cookies etc. So stack overflow can't identify the extra google accounts. You can change google accounts though - create another login - e.g. with github or facebook or email, then you can remove the current google login, change which user you're using with chrome or whatever browser, then login with github and add your other google login. Not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

The steps have changed slightly:

1. Go to your profile by clicking on your avatar.
2. Click on the "Settings" tab.
3. Click "Your logins" near the bottom on the left.
4. Then click the "Add more logins..." button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you, those old instructions were frustrating as they didn't match the current site.