# Use two Google Accounts with one SO account

Tags: support, user-accounts, login, google-openid

I am currently using Chrome on two computers, and each is linked to a different Google Account (one personal, one work). My Stack Overflow account is linked with my personal account, but I would like to use it with my work computer. I have read other questions' answers and found something that should work but does not: [How can I link two Google accounts to one Stack Exchange account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134379/how-can-i-link-two-google-apps-accounts-with-one-so-login)

This solution looks like it should work, but every time I reach step four instead of going to step five, I get logged into my current account. I have also tried it where I log into SO with my personal Gmail, then in Gmail, log in to my work Gmail. When I do step four, it asks if I want to login with that account not add it to my current one.

I don't know if this makes a difference, but I did create my SO account using the log into Google option. If this is the issue, I would like to know if it is possible to merge the two accounts into one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [adding an account](https://www.google.com/settings/) via the settings dashboard.

> [image: Google Account - Add Account]

That way, you should be logged into multiple accounts when going to step five.

Comment: Thank you this worked. You might want to add this to your solution on the linked question. Will I have to link the accounts the other way(login to my work one and add my personal to it) or is that irrelevant/taken care of?

Comment: I just added it to the other question, just wanted to make sure this work first. You should be able to log into StackOverflow via either account.