# Does "Add More Logins" not work OR is it misleading?

Tags: support, user-accounts, login, linked-accounts

Does "Add More Logins" not work OR is it misleading?

This is a simple question really:

I am logged into Stack with my Google openID account.   Within StackExchange there is a "my logins" tab inside my account prefs.  The wording of this "add more logins" implies to me that I can add a second Google account that would be mapped to the Stack account that I am currently logged into.

So, I try to add my alternate Google account, but whatever I do, it wants to create a second Stack account that is separate from my currently logged in Google Stack account.

The look and language of the "add more logins" popup implies to me that there is a one-to-many relationship between the One stack account and the Many other logins , which can include facebook or other google accounts, etc.

But, this does not seem to be the case.

Can anyone enlighten me on this or clarify this better in the documentation?  Perhaps, instead of calling it "add more logins" , you could call it, "add another account with a different login" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Add more logins" is right. You can have multiple logins (even multiple Google logins) associated with your account.

There's a bit of a trick to getting it to work with Google specifically. The details are described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134379/how-can-i-link-two-google-apps-accounts-with-one-so-login).

The problem is that once you sign out of your first Google account, you are by extension also signed out of Stack Exchange, so when you enter your second set of credentials, you're now registering for a new account instead of adding a login to your existing one (which you are now signed out of because you signed out of Google on your first account).

Two ways to get around that:

1. Add a temporary non-Google OpenID, sign in with that, and then add another Google account.
2. Follow the steps linked above involving enabling multi-sign-in on your Google account.

Comment: Ok, it is on my TODO list to try this.  I will check the green checkmark if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to clarify this for anyone else trying to add a second Google OpenID.

If you are just signed into the Google account used for StackExchange, when choosing Google in 'my logins / add more logins' you will be re-directed back to your profile.

You need to go directly to google.com first, click the active account, choose 'add account' and sign in so both are active on google.com at the same time.

Then back at StackExchange, when choosing to add a Google OpenID, it will give you the choice to add the secondary account.