# How do I merge 2 accounts from the same Google Account (different emails)?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, login, user-accounts, google

I recently changed my Google account primary email address for login from my old email address to a new one. I've also used Stack Overflow for the past few years with my Google account login. However, now that it's changed, I am seen as a new user.

Is there a way to get Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) to merge my old Google account login with the exisiting one (as they are the same Google account)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [this doesn't help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134379/how-can-i-link-two-google-apps-accounts-with-one-so-login), give our [user merge](https://stackoverflow.com/contact/user-merge) instructions a go.

You might have to email us in the end and provide some verification of the addresses used and whatnot, but we can cross that bridge when we come to it.

Comment: ♦ Tried that and it doesn't work as it's only related to 2 seperate google accounts. This is an account in which the primary login has changed details have changed. I've emailed, but still awaiting a reply.

Comment: @David I don't see any emails from you. Did you email `team@stackexchange.com`?

Comment: No, i used the contact form on stackoverflow. I'll email directly.

Comment: @David If you don't hear from us again, try emailing me directly - the address is in my profile.

Comment: Thanks Anna, all sorted now.