# Unable to add second gmail account to login

Tags: support, login, openid

When I first created my StackExchange account I used my work email address (we use Google Mail). But I'd actually prefer to have this account linked to my private email address instead. I've been trying to follow instructions here:

[How can I link two Google accounts to one Stack Exchange account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134379/how-can-i-link-two-google-accounts-to-one-stack-exchange-account)

Which doesn't seem to work. Whenever I click on "add a login using Google" it just takes me right back to my user profile page instead of giving me an option to add an account.
Any help on this would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Sign into StackExchange using your OpenID

   1. If you signed into StackExchange using your Google account, sign out of your Google account but not StackExchange
2. Follow the steps in [How can I link two Google accounts to one Stack Exchange account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134379/how-can-i-link-two-google-accounts-to-one-stack-exchange-account)
3. You should see the second account on your logins page:
   [image: Redacted screenshot showing two Google accounts]

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've opened an Incognito session of Chrome, logged into StackExchange with my Google account and tried again. Same result.

Comment: @koen best to send the team and email using the contact link at the bottom of the page then, there might be something unusual about your profiles.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just sent them a message. Will update here if I get a solution.