# How can I switch an account using Google accounts?

Tags: support, sign-up

How can I switch the account when using two Google accounts?

Note that I have visited this, *[How do I change my login provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers)* and *[How can I link two Google accounts to one Stack Exchange account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134379/how-can-i-link-two-google-accounts-to-one-stack-exchange-account)*.

But when I click to "Add more logins" and click "Add login with Google", it does nothing, and when I quit/exit my account and log in again use Google account, it doesn't even ask me which Google account it wants me to log in with... So, how do I switch two accounts that are both Google accounts?

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog I mean, first, where do I even get the same page in the answer? Second, I think that page was like a long time ago, now, MSO doesn't look like that. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: @lierwu the newer answer on the duplicate addresses the steps.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Thanks, but... somehow it didn't work??? It's the same steps as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers... QAQ

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356601/how-do-i-link-my-google-email-address-to-my-account-if-it-has-different-email?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1191473_356601